# MySQL IN Operator Not working

Tags: php, mysql

In MySql I used two `IN` operator but what the output I am getting is wrong.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(sub_category),category FROM `courses_table` WHERE category IN (3,4)
```

[this is the correct output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WENX5.png)

With this I am getting correct answer but when I used this I got some of unmatched rows, also I didn't before seen this type of error.

```
SELECT * FROM `sub_cat` 
WHERE cat_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT(sub_category) FROM `courses_table` WHERE category IN (3,4)) 
ORDER BY sub_value
```

[this is unmatched result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7odND.png)

This query gives output of unmatched result but child query gives correct answer.

Comment: db schemas and values: *Required*

Comment: *"also I didn't before seen this type of error"* - being what *exactly?*

Comment: If the tables are related, then use `JOIN`.

Comment: thanks join what correct option

Comment: Did you test that sub_cat has all of those cat_ids?  Or maybe the single answer is correct

Answer (score 0):

Well you see,

This query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(sub_category),category FROM `courses_table` WHERE category IN (3,4)
```

Is not the same as:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(sub_category) FROM `courses_table` WHERE category IN (3,4)
```

precisely because you have/dont have column `category` in each one. `Distinct` is a grouping function, hence, either you add `subcategory, category` to your `distinct` clause, or you add a `group by` clause to the first select.

On the other hand, as the other user stated, you can use a `INNER JOIN` Clause and add the `WHERE` subclause to that INNER. Also, if you always use category 3 and category 4, use a diferente clasue. Clause IN is slower.